# Simple SQL Server queries taking forever when variables/functions are involved

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is something that I've been struggling with for a while but always just found a way around it.
I have a fact table in a SQL Server DW that has around 30M records, and a integer field called DateCreatedKey which has a non-clustered index on the field. 
Then I also have a function called `dbo.fn_DateKeyFromDate` which is quite simply

```
declare @ret int = Year(@date) * 10000 + Month(@date) * 100 + Day(@date) 
return @ret
```

As you will see from the execution times below, it is as if the index doesn't work properly when using the function or when using a variable. 
Not sure if I'm missing something obvious?

Now these are the execution times for each of these 5 blocks of code:

- **A: 0.034s:**

  ```
  SELECT  * 
  INTO    #subs2
  FROM    biWarehouse.dbo.factSubscriptions WITH (NOLOCK) 
  where   DateCreatedKey >= 20170814
  ```
- **B: 15.4s:**

  ```
  declare @fromdate int
  select  @fromdate = 20170814

  SELECT  * 
  INTO    #subs3
  FROM    biWarehouse.dbo.factSubscriptions WITH (NOLOCK) 
  where   DateCreatedKey >= @fromdate
  ```
- **C: 134s:**

  ```
  SELECT  * 
  INTO    #subs4
  FROM    biWarehouse.dbo.factSubscriptions WITH (NOLOCK) 
  where   DateCreatedKey >= dbo.fn_DateKeyFromDate(GETDATE()-1)
  ```
- **D: 20s:**

  ```
  declare @fromdate int
  select  @fromdate = dbo.fn_DateKeyFromDate(GETDATE()-1)

  SELECT  * 
  INTO    #subs 
  FROM    biWarehouse.dbo.factSubscriptions WITH (NOLOCK) 
  where   DateCreatedKey >= @fromdate
  ```

Comment: can  you post execution plan for one query which is running fast and slow

Comment: you can use this link to post the plan :https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/  i believe you might have some data type conversions

Comment: The 4th query is the same as the 3rd query. Perhaps you could tag your queries with A, B , C etc. so we can refer to them. I know that in some cases functions don't stop fields being SARGable, but I avoid them anyway. You might get better performance from a persisted calculated column with an index. I believe that `dbo.fn_DateKeyFromDate(GETDATE()-1)` will be evaluated for every row when it is used in a where clause. The query plan will tell you for sure.

Comment: Thank you, these are the links to the execution plans.

Comment: I'm curious: what happens to your results if you declare your function `WITH SCHEMABINDING`? (See [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1692/using-schema-binding-to-improve-sql-server-udf-performance/) for an example.) And what version of SQL Server are you running? (`SELECT @@VERSION`)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that indexes doesn't get used when calling a function, but it should work with a variable. I would compare the execution plans to be sure.

Try this if you want to use the function (maybe that your idea with the 130s example?):

```
declare @fromdate int
select  @fromdate = dbo.fn_DateKeyFromDate(GETDATE()-1)

SELECT  * 
INTO    #subs 
FROM    biWarehouse.dbo.factSubscriptions WITH (NOLOCK) 
where   DateCreatedKey >= @fromdate
```

Comment: You're right, well spotted. However the execution for that query is still 20s  which is appox 600 times longer than it should be

Comment: @Niel Bear in mind that your server caches, among many other factors, might be varying the speed results you're seeing. If you want to find out whether queries are doing the same thing, check their query plans.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to see the query plan for C, but I assume it will point me to that function.  But A is fast because you are using a literal and SQL knows how to handle that value.

B and D are slower due to the use of a local variable.  Read here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/

I would imagine if you created a stored proc and passed in the value your execution time would fall greatly.

Or you could test it by adding a RECOMPILE query hint, that would allow the optimizer to use the correct statistics.